# evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+2x^4)e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to evaluate

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+2x^4)e^{-x^2} dx$$

**solution i tried**-The given function in the integral i.e $(1+2x^4)e^{-x^2}$ is a even function so by property of even function we can write it as

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+2x^4)e^{-x^2} dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}(1+2x^4)e^{-x^2} dx$$
>   $$\implies2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2} dx+4\int_{0}^{\infty}x^4e^{-x^2} dx\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;...(1)$$
>   we know that value of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$

so from this (1) will become

> $$2\times\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}+4\int_0^{\infty}x^4e^{-x^2}dx$$

The doubt here is that i have n idea how to solve the second part ,I tried to put $x^2=t$ but still not get the answer please provide me a hint so that i can solve it further

Thank you

Comment: Use integration by parts twice on the second term, it simplifies to a term in a similar form. That gives a recurrence relation which is easy to solve. Also,it helps if you know the Gamma integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the substitution $t=x^2$ does work:

$$2\int_{0}^\infty x^4 \exp(-x^2)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty t^{\frac32}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm dt=\Gamma\left(\frac52\right)=\frac{3\sqrt\pi}4,$$

see [particular values of the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function) or [Gamma function of positive half-integer](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gamma_Function_of_Positive_Half-Integer).

Comment: Shouldn't there be $\frac{1}{2}$ when we change it to t

Comment: @Mathsmerizing thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Since $\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}a^{-1/2}$, applying $\partial_a^2$ gives $\int_{\Bbb R}x^4e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac34\sqrt{\pi}a^{-5/2}$. Now take $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^n.e^{-x^2}dx$ $\Rightarrow I_n=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}.2xe^{-x^2}dx$

Using by parts we get $I_n=\frac{1}{2}x^{n-1}.\frac{e^{-x^2}}{-1}|^\infty_0-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}(n-1)x^{n-2}.\frac{e^{-x^2}}{-1}dx$

$I_n=0+\frac{n-1}{2}I_{n-2}$

$I_4=\frac{4-1}{2}\frac{2-1}{2}.I_0$

$I_4=\frac{3}{8}\sqrt\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2n} e^{-x^2} dx=\Gamma(n+1/2)$$
So yhe Given integgral is $$I=I_0+2I_2=[\Gamma(1/2)+2 \Gamma(1/2+2)]=[\sqrt{\pi}
+2\Gamma(5/2)]=\sqrt{\pi}+(3/2)\sqrt{\pi} =\frac{5 \sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By parts,

$$\int x^4e^{-x^2}dx=\frac12\int x^3\,2xe^{-x^2}dx=-\frac12x^3e^{-x^2}+\frac12\int6x^2e^{-x^2}.$$

Integrating by parts a second time, you will get rid of the factor $x^2$.

---

**Alternatively,**

$$(P(x)e^{-x^2})'=(P'(x)-2xP(x))e^{-x^2}$$

and you can solve

$$P'(x)-2xP(x)=1+2x^4$$ where the solution will be a cubic polynomial.

> $$(3ax^2+2bx+c)-2x(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=1+2x^4\to P(x)=-x^3-\frac{3x}2.$$

Note that an extra term is needed.